# EF Code First foreign key without navigation property, but with parent collection property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20886049/1628429) one, but in this case I *do* have a collection property on the parent referring to the childeren:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And just as with the cited question, I don't want/need a `Parent` property on `Child`.

So how should the following syntax be altered to define the relationship?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Parent)   <---- no such property "Parent"
    .WithMany(p => p.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `WithRequired` method without parameter:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>() 
    .HasMany(p => p.Children)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

`With` part can be left empty if there is no inverse navigation property.

Comment: Ah--I didn't realized the association could be defined on the parent's end. This works in practice (EF upholds the relationship when creating, deleting, etc)?

Comment: Yes, the one to many relationship is going to be created in your DB, so it will uphold the relationship when you do all CRUD operations