# EF Core: Add related objects together without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am following this strategy to create relations without navigation property
[EF Code First foreign key without navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886049/ef-code-first-foreign-key-without-navigation-property) (first answer)

Now what I wonder is that: If I have 2 objects with relationship

```
Parent { int Id, int ChildId } 
Child { int Id, int ParentId }
```

As right now both Id is not yet created and there is no navigation property to link them. How can I add both parent and child in one `dbContext.SaveChanges()`

Comment: First, why wouldn't you establish the FK relationship? Second, there's no need to have the relationship in both the parent and child. The child should have the parent's Id as a FK. There shouldn't be a ChildId in the parent. If it's a 1:1 relationship you can either merge to a single entity or use the Parent.Id as the Child's PK.

Comment: Without a navigation property it's impossible if the primary keys are db-generated.