# How to define foreign key with only identifier in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I would like to define foreign key in C# DB Context (method `OnModelCreating`) using only identifier column.

All examples I saw relies on assumption you have C# reference within types, like:

```
public sealed class Answer
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public  User User { get; set; } = null!;
...
```

so then you write:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>(entity =>
{
  ...
  entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Answers)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

But how to define (in C#) foreign key when the type does not have reference and only identifier, like this:

```
public sealed class Answer
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
...
```

*Solution -- "add reference and then follow the examples" does not count :-).*

Comment: What's your use case? I guess it's a API for a single table and therefore, no `User` entities

Comment: Why do it need this reference? The entity (class) `User` exists?

Comment: @Cid, the other table exists. I simply don't want to add a reference between types, only identifiers.

Comment: @vernou Well, I don't see method `HasForeignKey` directly defined on `entity` object (when defining `Entity` in model builder). The class `User` exists (and table as well).

Comment: @greenoldman did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886049/ef-code-first-foreign-key-without-navigation-property) ?